# Hiding UIButton in different view?

Tags: objective-c

In my app delegate, I have a IBOutlet for a UIButton that is linked to a different view. The view is displayed like this:

```
// .h
IBOutlet UIView *theToolbar;

// .m
[window addSubview:theToolbar];
theToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 44);
```

And here's how I do it all in my app delegate:

```
// .h
IBOutlet UIButton *disbledCameraButton;
@property (copy, readwrite) UIButton *disabledCameraButton;

// .m
@synthesize disabledCameraButton;
```

And lastly, I try to hide it in a different class:

```
#import "TableViewAppDelegate.h"
TableViewAppDelegate *dataCeter = (TableViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dataCeter.disbledCameraButton.hidden = YES;
```

However, I get this error:

```
accessing unknown disabledCameraButton getter Method
```

Why is this doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few typos in there. Fix those and it should work.

disbled / disabled

Comment: Silly me... Wow... I feel stupid... Also had to use `nonatomic, retain` property.